# Related statement of invariance of domain

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Is is possible to construct a example below?

Let $U$ be open in $\Bbb R^n$, $f:U\to f(U)$ be one-to-one and continuous and $f(U)$ be open in $\Bbb R^m$. But $f^{-1}$ is not continuous and $n\neq m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f:U\rightarrow f(U)$ be a continuous one-to-one map from open $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ to open subset $f(U)\subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$. We show that $n=m$.

Write $U = \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}K_n$, where $K_n$ are compact sets. Since 
$$f(U) = \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}f(K_n)$$
we derive by Baire category theorem that there exists $n_0$ such that $f(K_{n_0})$ contains an open subset $V$ of $f(U)$. Now consider the restriction  $g:K_{n_0}\rightarrow f(K_{n_0})$ of $f$. Then $g$ is a homeomorphism, because it is closed. Now the restriction of $g$ to a map $g^{-1}(V)\rightarrow V$ is a homeomorphism. Since $g^{-1}(V)\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and $V\subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ are open, we derive that $n=m$.

Comment: Thanks. So it seems nontrivial for beginners to find a counterexample?

Comment: @Eric I edited my answer. Now it implies that there are no such examples.

Comment: Baire category theorem is advanced to me currently. However, knowing the theorem you proved being true is enough for my purpose now! Thanks.